# Clear workspace with user-defined void function in R

Tags: r, function, workspace

I would like to have a simple function to clear my workspace in R, but I seem to be having issues. I have my code below.

```
clear() = function() rm(list=ls())
```

When I define this function and call it by simply using `clear()`, the code executes but my workspace is not cleared. I tried various formats of defining the function to see if anything funky was going on, but it all gives the same result. Simply using the `rm(list=ls())` function works, but not when I embed it in my function. Can anyone point me in the right direction? And what am I not understanding about user-defined R functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `ls()` inside a function it returns the objects in the environment of that function by default. Same with `rm()`.

Try this:

```
clear <- function() {
  rm(list=ls(.GlobalEnv), envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

Comment: Great! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the explanation!